# NoMethodError for array in specific view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nomethoderror

Here is the error I am receiving

```
    NoMethodError in Restaurants#index


undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass
```

When I try to add :

Address: <%= @restaurant.address %>

(note that this <%=@restaurant.address%> works in restaurants/Show.html.erb

to my array :

```
     <%= div_for(@restaurants, :class => "container") do |restaurant| %>
    <div class="row carousel-row">
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the @ symbol. Your variable in the for-loop is `restaurant` so you can access the address with

`<p>Address: <%= restaurant.address %></p>`